# Output to an op-amp differentiator circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, pspice

In an op-amp differentiator circuit, this is the input (VPULSE) to the circuit:

[image]

Would my output look like this?

[image: ini]

If not how would you fix the simulation settings?

Comment: No it wouldn't. Your circuit looks highly unstable. Also, in future plot input and output together so they can be more easily compared.

Comment: I certainly hope not.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose your circuit is an "ideal" differentiator? A feedback path with just one capacitor and one resistor ?

This circuit will always be unstable because the opamp behaves (nearly) like a 2nd-order lowpass. Together with the feedback network (1st-order lowpass) the loop gain will violate the stability criterion (loop gain magnitude still larger than 0dB for 360deg loop phase shift).

You should use a resistor in series with the capacitor. The price for the stabilization is a reduced range of frequencies where the circuit can differentiate.

**EDIT:**  Here are some hints for finding an appropriate value for the additional (compensating) resistor Rs:

When **wo=1/RfCs** (Feedback resistor Rf, Series capactor Cs) and wt is the transit frequency for the opamp (first-order model), then the resistor Rs can be calculated (for a phase margin of app. 45 deg) as

**Rs=Rf/SQRT(wt/wo)**

Comment: yes the circuit is composed of one capacitor and resistor

Comment: The value of the additional resistor depends on the used opamp. Start with a rather low value (100 ohms) and see if the circuit still oscillates. If necessary - try larger values.

Comment: See also here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/430405/finding-vout-and-gain-of-a-differential-amplifier